# Moving between scenes

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to move to another scene after login in my application. Which component should i use? I tried to use NavigatorIOS but if I use **push** then appears back button in navbar; tried to use **replace** function instead of **replace**, but replace doesn't change title.

Which component should I use and how to approach it?

Answer (score 0):

I use `Navigator` rather than `NavigatorIOS`, but maybe the same principle applies:

In the background the navigator has an array of routes that it keeps for example:

`[login]`

When you use `push(newRoute)` you end up with:

`[login, newRoute]`

Hence seeing a back button. Instead you could do: `navigator.replace(newRoute)` and you'd end up with:

`[newRoute]`

That way you wouldn't have a back button.

I hope this helps.